# Example regex match?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match one little piece of information from a text file and am having some difficulties. If anyone wouldn't mind posting some small example codes on how they would go about doing a match regex, or have some great example websites to hand out, it would be very welcomed.

My confusion lies in whether or not there needs to be some sort of if statement, and then what variable I need and what it equals. I do understand the setup of the match though (=~ m/22:28/)   <---which is what I am really using in my code.

so the fogginess lies in this area and I'm putting in random info for example.

```
if (i=~ m/22:28/)
```

something to that nature. So thanks in advance if you can help!!

Comment: You need the `$` sigil on `i` if it's a variable.

Comment: ah yes I forgot the $ my bad and thanks for the site!

Comment: You don't really ask a question. If you describe what it is you want to do then I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: i would love to but it is quite a long explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m/22:28/
```

is short for

```
$_ =~ m/22:28/
```

It check if `$_` matches the regex pattern `22:28`, which is to say it check if `$_` contains the string `22:28`.

You can substitute `$_` for a different variable if you wish.

```
$i =~ m/22:28/
```

You don't have to use it in `if` condition expression, but it wouldn't make much sense to discard the result.

The following are all effectively the same:

```
if (!($i =~ m/22:28/)) { die }
if ($i !~ m/22:28/) { die }
die if $i !~ m/22:28/;
die unless $i =~ m/22:28/;
$i =~ m/22:28/ or die;
my $matched = $i =~ m/22:28/;  die if !$matched;
```

Comment: so the 22:28 is a time. If i wanted to use the variable $start_time = "22:28" and then did  .....if ($start_time =~ m/^22:28/)...would that workout? I need to output what it matches eventually.

Comment: No, it's a regex pattern. If you want to make a regex pattern from a string, you can use `quotemeta` or `\Q..\E`. (`/\Q$start_time\E/`) keep in mind that will also match `122:28`

Answer (score 0):

For a tutorial, check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html.

But your regex is looking for a verbatim string - why not use a simple string function for that?